# Using they to reference non-person entities?

Tags: relative-pronouns, grammar-myths

Suppose the following situation where I'm talking about artifacts.

"Debit and credit notes are" ... Is it correct to reference Debit and credit notes later on by using the subject "They are ..."?

It might be a simple answer but for non native english speaker it makes me wonder if is it correct or not.

Comment: yes. obviously! go with *they*.

Comment: or "such notes are"...

Comment: @MaulikV - wouldn't "those" be a better fit?

Comment: @ddriver We generally use *'those'* when we 'point' at them. Say - those are the people who vandalized the premises. However, i'm not dead sure on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, this is definitely okay!

*Third person plural* is always "they", regardless of gender.